# nextjs localStorage getItem

Tags: next.js

after searching half a day I still not able to getItem from local storage.

the idea is to save some data to local storage and based on that I want to route a user in the Layout component. I am able to save to local storage and delete but not able to get data from it. I get error 'local storage not defined' or 'destroy is not a function'

I have 3 components save, delete and get. save and delete I execute after a client side api call, the get function I need to be working in the Layout as it is the top level for all routes.

I Need a bit help to the right direction please.

---Upadte

I found something that works

```
export const IsAuth = ()=>{
    const [auth, setAuth] = useState();
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(typeof windows === undefined) return;
        const item = localStorage.getItem('ltu');
        setAuth(!!item);
    },[]);
    return auth;
}
```

now my problem is I have not much understanding of nextjs. I used the Layout to create a theme template, I basically have only 3 pages that can be visited if not logged in and the rest one needs to be logged in. I get so many examples but it seems like I need to verify auth on every single page instead of being able to do this on root/layout level.

all examples I get are without the use of Layout and I am totally stuck.

I want a simple login system just with jwt and check if thats there to show pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get the `localStorage.getItem()` to work in the layout template.

My solution while maybe not perfect is.

In the `_app.js` I create `useState()` and pass those along to the menu trough the Layout, in in the menu `useEffect()` with 'use client' in the useEffect I set the state I need global.

`_app.js`:

```
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [isAuth, setAuth] = useState()
  const [user, setUser] = useState()

  return (
    <Layout setAuth={setAuth} isAuth={isAuth} user={user} setUser={setUser}>
      <Component user={user} setUser={setUser} isAuth={isAuth} {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

`Layout.js`:

```
export default function Layout({ children, setAuth, isAuth, user, setUser }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Headd />
      <SideMenu setAuth={setAuth} isAuth={isAuth} user={user} setUser={setUser}/>
      <main>
        <div className="menu-spacer"></div>
        <content>
          {children}
        </content>
      </main>
    </>
  )
}
```

`menu.js`:

```
'use client';
const SideMenu = ({setAuth, isAuth, user, setUser}) => {
 useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof windows === undefined) return;
    const item = localStorage.getItem('ltu');
    setAuth(!!item);
    if (item)
      setUser(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Ud')))
  }, [router, router.isReady])
}
```

Now I can use the {isAuth, user,} on any page and component.

I am pretty sure this is not the right solution, but I could not find any other working solution and no one here yet posted a answer.